# Cloudfront origin path regex

Tags: regex, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

It is possible to define a regex value in the `OriginPath` property in a Cloudfront definitions? My bucket is structured in the following way:

`my-bucket/v1.0.0/`

and the version change periodically. is it possible to write the `OriginPath` in a regex form?

Comment: It sounds like you may be misunderstanding what Origin Path is used for, or perhaps something else about how it works.  It's not a pattern match -- it's a static value to prepend to the path on requests sent to this origin.  If Origin Path is set to `/foo` then CloudFront sends a request for `GET /index.html` to the origin server as though the browser originally requested `GET /foo/index.html`.   CloudFront has no idea whether this will result in a valid request from the origin's perspective -- it just does it, because you've configured it to.  Not sure what your objective is.

Comment: ok thank you now gotcha :-)

Comment: What should we do with this question, at this point? I can answer it as written for the benefit of future readers who have made the same assumption as you, but I need to understand exactly what you originally thought Origin Path was used for. Perhaps you had it confused with or thought it needed a value like the cache behavior attribute [`Path Pattern`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-web-values-specify.html#DownloadDistValuesPathPattern)?  Otherwise perhaps you'll edit it to clarify what you are asking, if you still have a question.